# VBA to write each day between a data range in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a form in Excel that asks for a start and end date.  Then, I need to write a VBA script that writes out each day within that range in the first blank cell in column A.

So, for example, if it was given:

```
Start Date: 1/5/2017
End Date: 1/9/2017
```

The Result would be:

```
1/5/2017
1/6/2017
1/7/2017
1/8/2017
1/9/2017
```

Then if it is run again with a new date range, the dates would append to the bottom of the list.  This is just a short example, in practice the date ranges would be much larger and consist of several months.

I'm not really sure where to begin with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Excel stores dates as numbers with `1` = `1 Jan 1900`. So coding should be simple.  Be aware that this is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) mentioned, a date in VBA is only a number that can be increased or decreased with simple numeric operations. This code should do exactly what you want:

```
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = DateSerial(2017, 1, 1)
endDate = DateSerial(2017, 1, 23)

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("Table1")
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

While startDate <= endDate
    sheet.Cells(i, 1) = startDate
    startDate = startDate + 1
    i = i + 1
Wend
```