# How to dynamically create or populate a worksheet with multiple rows, from a date range in a single row in another table

Tags: excel

Given an existing excel TABLE with two date columns, representing the start date and end date.  I would like to expand that table into a second excel TABLE in a different worksheet, so that there is one row for each of the dates between start and end.  So for each row in the source table, add one row (in the target worksheet) for each date between start and end.

```
SOURCE TABLE:

    |------------|------------|------------|------------|
    |Person      |Fruit       |Start       |End         |
    |------------|------------|------------|------------|
    |Bob         |Apple       | 01/07/2019 | 04/07/2019 |
    |Anna        |Orange      | 03/07/2019 | 05/07/2019 |
    |------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

```
TARGET TABLE:

    |------------|------------|------------|
    |Date        |Person      |Fruit       |
    |------------|------------|------------|
    | 01/04/2019 | Bob        | Apple      |
    | 02/04/2019 | Bob        | Apple      |
    | 03/04/2019 | Bob        | Apple      |
    | 04/04/2019 | Bob        | Apple      |
    | 03/04/2019 | Anna       | Orange     |
    | 04/04/2019 | Anna       | Orange     |
    | 05/04/2019 | Anna       | Orange     |
    |------------|------------|------------|
```

A simple solution would create (or select) the target worksheet and generate all the rows required based on the data in the source.

An advanced solution would check the target worksheet to see if the rows already exist, and delete any that are not in the range.  Note - I am adding this for the excel enthusiasts that really like to nail a solution.  This is actually what I require, but I can build on the simple solution myself if required.

My motivation to do this is that Excel pivots and charting work best when there is a line of data in an excel TABLE for each item being analysed, much like how you would model the solution in a database.

For example, to chart the demand for oranges over time, a good pivot chart needs a single row for each date, rather than two dates expressing the start and end of the demand period (if that makes sense).  Sure, you can do it with some indexing and cruel pivoting, but the user story for this spreadsheet makes that technique impossible.  It must be generated automatically.

EDIT: Just adding that I appreciate that I can achieve this by adding a column for each date into the source table, and using Transform Data to generate the dataset.  However, the design of the real world source table (rather than this example) has limitations set by the user that prevent me from doing so.  I do also have a working method where I copy the source table to a temporary sheet, and then run a transform on that, but the user would like me to try to avoid doing that (ho-hum!)

Comment: I guess you have more dates, because the input and the output is not aligned, depending on which version of excel you are using I would search for unpivot options (older versions wouldn't have it)

Comment: Hi Anna, thank you for looking at this.  I am not sure what you mean by the date alignment.  In the source table, 'Anna, Orange' has a date range of only 3 days, while 'Bob, Apple' has a range covering 5 days.  So Bob has 5 rows in the target table, while Anna has only 3.  Is this what you were referring to?

Also, Unipivot is a great tool, but would only help if I had dated columns rather than a range.  However, it's a good suggestion, and if I can't find another solution, I can use the range in the original table to populate those columns and unipivot to rotate as you suggest.  Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are going to need VBA to do this. Much [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807431/vba-to-write-each-day-between-a-data-range-in-excel) with a few more bells and whistles.